# Is there a cleaner way to file upload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to upload a file using laravel 5. I have a form that takes the file, moves it to the desired destination and saves a record inside of the database as well.

I have the following inside of my controller:

```
public function store(DestinationWeddingRequest $request)
    {
        $this->upload($request, $fileName);

        DestinationWedding::create([
            'description' => $request->get('description'),
            'image_url'   => $fileName
        ]);

        return redirect('destination-weddings');
    }
```

Another method inside of my controller:

```
public function upload(DestinationWeddingRequest $request, &$fileName)
    {
        $fileName = mt_rand();

        $destinationPath = public_path('/images/upload/destination_weddings');
        $request->file('image_url')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    }
```

I want to know if this is the correct way to do it, or do I need to use some kind of mutator inside of the model?

Answer (score 2):

I would preferably fire an event when the file was uploaded and perform the action within the event. This way you will get a cleaner controller and you can easily manage everything with it.

**Event:**

```
namespace optimizer\Events;

use App\Events\Event;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class FileWasUploaded extends Event {

    use SerializesModels;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $request;


     /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param $request
     * 
     */
    public function __construct($request)
    {

        $this->request = $request;

    }

}
```

**EventHandler:**

```
namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Events\FileWasUploaded;


class whenFileWasUploaded {

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  FileWasUploaded  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(FileWasUploaded $event)
    {
        $fileName = mt_rand();

        $destinationPath = public_path('/images/upload/destination_weddings');
        $event->file('image_url')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

        DestinationWedding::create([
            'description' => $event->description,
            'image_url'   => $fileName
        ]);

    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(DestinationWeddingRequest $request)
{
    event(new FileWasUploaded($request));
    return redirect('destination-weddings');
}
```

Then simply add the event to your **EventServiceProvider:**

```
protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\FileWasUploaded' => [
            'App\Handlers\Events\whenFileWasUploaded@handle'
        ],
    ];
```

You need to adjust the namespaces and possibly the uses. To verify everything in your event, simply use

```
dd($event);
```

in your handler, you will then see everything that is callable within the event (might be that this line `$event->file('image_url')` needs to be called differently)

If you have many similar but not equal cases where you need to upload something, consider using a command, too.

To create the event more convenient, start with editing your EventServiceProvider.php like I have mentioned above and then call

```
php artisan event:generate
```

That way, laravel will create templates for both event and handler at once.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try as soon as i get the chance!